# Permissions issues when uploading plugins from Wordpress locally

Tags: php, wordpress, lampp

I'm trying to work on Wordpress locally via localhost with Xampp. The issue comes when I try to download plugins.

It says:

> Installation failed: Could not create directory.

I'm guessing it's permissions issue. I tried many things like

```
chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins
chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins
```

I'm quite new to Ubuntu so I tried a bunch of things similar to the above to try and find the directory that needed permissions

**Solution

It worked for me -->

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: never **ever** set your permissions to 777 - change to 755 (for directories) and 644 (for files)

Comment: 755 doesn't work for me... Only 777 does. There is probably something else wrong then.